# Using .htaccess to force a subdomain/CNAME redirect to HTTPS

Tags: .htaccess, ssl-certificate, cname

While I'm certain that this must exist in other questions, I find myself struggling to adapt answers I've found to my use case.

My clients direct their users to visit a transactional link, such as **sub.client.com/abc**

My clients have a CNAME record set up that directs **sub** to my subdomain, which is **user.example.com**

Since my clients do not provide links with http or https, the path for the end user seems to be;

**sub.client.com/abc** -> user.example.com/abc -> http://example.com/user/abc (Of course, to the end user, the domain still remains as **sub.client.com/abc** in their browser, but with an insecure warning).

Ideally, my path for the end user would be **sub.client.com/abc** -> user.example.com/abc -> https://example.com/user/abc.  In my .htaccess, I have the following;

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^user\.(.*)\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /user/pages/$1 [NC,L]
```

I have a valid SSL certificate for **user.example.com**, but cannot determine what change I can make in the .htaccess file to ensure end users do not see an insecure warning.

Comment: SSL cert should be for whatever URL shown in browser. So in your case your client needs to have a SSL cert for `sub.client.com`. Having a cert for `user.example.com` doesn't really help.

Comment: If you want `sub.client.com` to remain showing in the address bar, then _of course_ a valid SSL certificate for _that_ host name is needed. Without one, the connection between the user and that host simply _is not_ secure, so anything else _but_ that warning showing would be incorrect.

Comment: You need to read a bit about how the http protocol works. A URL like the `sub.client.com/abc` does not make any sense, it does not exist, it is invalid. The browser _always_ uses either http or https to make a request. Only some of todays browsers think it is a great idea to not show that.